# Coinbase Webhooks: is there a list of all data available?

Tags: documentation, webhooks, coinbase-api

I am looking into the webhook [notifications](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#notifications) and I am struggling to find documentation...

I would need to find the different payload for the "data" in the notification response...

the documentation only have one example: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#show-a-notification

it is almost impossible to built an app if I need to try and see every type of notification by myself... (trial and error approach :( )

any extra resource? any help here?

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

On [this page](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/notifications), there is a link that says

> See full list of notifications and corresponding payload information

But guess what, it links to the pages in your OP.

Even CB's newest documentation doesn't outline the payload until you run a sample to get the result displayed in the docs page. [Here is a simple example](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getcurrencies), just click `Try It` to see the payload. It's not a bad thing until you need to see the payload of a signed request, then it's a PITA...

I've never used their webhooks to know how the payload differs but considering their docs you may need to run each notification to see what to expect and save the result to refer to later.

Comment: but this seems for the REST API... will it be the same for webhookS?

I mean, what payload will I get when I get a deposit into my account? what payload will I get when I buy ETH from Fiat?? and when I sell BTC for XRP?

this is what I am looking for...

Comment: as i said "you may need to run each notification to see what to expect and save the result to refer to later." you wouldn't have to do it for each trading pair because the format will be the same but you may need to trigger them to see the payload and save the results.